# Using Custom IComparer to Order by Pointer value

Tags: c#, linq

I have a class that defines a student, and has a property (FollowedBy) that is immediately behind that student. I am looking for a way to order the students based on this linkage.

```
class Student
{
     public int StudentID { get; set; }   
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public int? FollowedBy { get; set; }
}

var lstStudents = new List<Student>()
{ new Student() { StudentID = 2, Name = "Mark", FollowedBy =4 },
 new Student() { StudentID = 1, Name = "Sam", FollowedBy = 2},
 new Student() { StudentID = 4, Name = "Fred", FollowedBy =null } ,
 new Student() { StudentID = 3, Name = "Janice", FollowedBy = 1}};

  for (var s in     lstStudents.OrderBy(x => ????))
  {
         console.Write(s.Name);
  }

 // The output I'm looking for
 //  Janice
 //  Sam
 //  Mark
 //  Fred
```

Comment: Ok. I'll reword it.

Comment: I'm not sure you can determine the ordering by just comparing 2 elements. 
Compare Janice and Mark. You won't know who is first without bringing Sam into the picture

Comment: It doesn't even make sense to use a sort in the first place.  Find the root node and follow the chain, like any other graph traversal problem out there.  It's an O(n) operation, unlike a sort.  Both simpler and faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    public List<Student> GetOrderedStudents(List<Student> students)
    {
        Student[] reverseOrder = new Student[students.Count];

        Student last = students.Single(s => s.FollowedBy == null);

        reverseOrder[0] = last;
        Student next = last;

        for (var i = 1; i < students.Count; i++)
        {
            next = students.Single(s => s.FollowedBy == next.StudentID);
            reverseOrder[i] = next;
        }

        return reverseOrder.Reverse().ToList();  
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

What you're trying to do isn't strictly sorting, and it won't support certain sort algorithms that rely on comparitive principles like `A > B > C => A > C` without making the implementation of `IComparer` aware of the entire set. Such an `IComparer` is likely to run much slower than simply sorting using a search.

It seems it would be easier to make this into a helper method (extension method if you want to use linq-like syntax) which used its own mechanics in order to search the set for each `FollowedBy`/`StudentID` combo.

Comment: The requirements aren't that the "followed by" node be *anywhere after* it in the sequence, but rather that it *immediately follow* it, so it is in fact a well-defined sequence that you could (although probably wouldn't want to) generate via a traditional sorting mechanism.

Comment: I'm not worried about performance. The list will generally be less than a dozen items.

Comment: @Servy I'm aware of this, but wouldn't Quicksort (that used by ,NET) avoid making all possible comparisons (resulting in O(N^2)) and thus not catch all 'x-after-y' instances?

Comment: @Aravol You can, without *too* much difficulty, compute the "distance from the root node" for any arbitrary node.  You could then sort on that.  Of course, if you've already computed all of those indexes, you've already done all of the work needed to create the sequence, so there's no *need* to sort on it, but your assertion that it's not *possible* to sort it is false, it's just not going to be particularly *productive*.

Comment: @Servy hence "make the comparer aware of the entire set" - I admit I misphrased my meaning and shall update accordingly!

Comment: It is your first sentence that is wrong, not the second.  Also, such a comparer could be pretty trivially made to perform well by simply creating a lookup.  It could compare the objects in (amortized) O(1) time.

Answer (score 2):

You can find the root and then follow `FollowedBy`:

```
  Dictionary<int, Student> dict = lstStudents
    .ToDictionary(item => item.StudentID);

  // root
  Student s = dict[lstStudents
    .Select(item => item.StudentID)
    .Except(lstStudents
       .Where(item => item.FollowedBy.HasValue)
       .Select(item => item.FollowedBy.Value))
    .First()];

  for (; s != null; s = s.FollowedBy == null? null : dict[s.FollowedBy.Value]) {
    Console.WriteLine(s.Name);
  }
```